# cant get my post() to work using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

As HTML, JavaScript and all that belongs to it is very new to me I more often than not get stuck at some issue.

Today my issue is that I'm not sure how to get my script to post() what I put in my input fields.

I have 3 input fields in my HTML that should take firstname, lastname and email and send it to a database (mysql) when I press the button to perform the function.

Simply put, my HTML looks like this:

```
    <form id="regForm">
        <div>
            <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
            <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
            <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email"/>
        </div>
            <button id="regBtn" type="button">Click Me</button>
   </form>
```

Now to the tricky bit :( my script file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#regBtn").click(function() {
        $.post("example.ex/register")
        //I dont know what to do here// 
    });
});
```

I have searched for and tried some examples but Im doing something wrong.
something like this?

```
   //This is an example//
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#regBtn").click(function() {
        $.post("example.ex/register"),
        {
           firstname: "#firstname",
           lastname: "#lastname",
           email: "#email"
        }
    });
});
```

How do I send my firstname, lastname and email from my inputs as parameters?
Please help me understand how this works. Thank you.

Comment: You send using the data: property of the $.post(). Remember, if you send it in something like json, you have to JSON.parse(your data) so it can be understood by the post. Just a heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need yo grab the values from the inputs.

In your javascript replace `"#firstname"` with `$('#firstname').val()`

This is assuming your firstname input has an id of firstname

Comment: That was really all that was needed.... man... so simple. I was close tho :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You should try and read the documentation [API of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). Here you can see how to make a POST call with jQuery, including examples. This will help you a long the way.

But I will give you a little code which might help you in the right direction.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#regBtn").click(function() {
        $.post("example.ex/register", $('#regForm').serializeArray(), function(response) {

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I managed to get it working. I will absolutely read up on this, I started learning jQuery this week so i will get there in time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

the standard way to POST using jQuery is like the following example:

```
$.post( "PAGE_URL", { DATA_TO_BE_SENT_GOES_HERE } );
```

so in your example you will need to make your code like the following:

```
$.post("example.ex/register",
        {
           firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
           lastname: $("#lastname").val(),
           email: $("#email").val()
        });
```

the problem with your block of code was a typo here:

```
$.post("example.ex/register"), {YOUR_DATA};
```

while the correct one should be like:

```
$.post("example.ex/register", {YOUR_DATA});
```

You have simply closed the function before providing the data which should be sent with your call.

Another isue to tackle is that you most probably want to notify the user upon successfully receiving the data that the action is completed successfully, this is accomplished using the following signature while calling `$.post()`:

```
$.post( "PAGE_URL", { name: "Test", time: "10AM" }, success: FUNCTION_TO_EXCUTE_ON_SUCCESS() );
```

so back to your code, it should be something like that:

```
$.post("example.ex/register",
        {
           firstname: $("#firstname").val(),
           lastname: $("#lastname").val(),
           email: $("#email").val()
        },success: function(){
alert("Action completed successfully") // please make a better UI decision than altering the user, this is just an example :)
    });
```

hope this helps.

Comment: This is how I solved it thanks to you guys here at stackoverflow. it was simpler than I thought